# How to run pyautogui headless on Windows

Tags: python, pyautogui

I have a python script that runs on Windows server 2012 that goes into an app and do some tasks (not a website).

and im trying to run this headless, and i found PyVirtualDisplay but seems like this library doesnt work on windows.

any other alternatives?

thank you!

Comment: Searching for the same solution. I also have python app using pyautogui and i need to somehow run. The problem with running it on a Windows VPS is when i want to login into the VPS it would take the mouse control. I am also searching for a solution here. If you have any update, please let me know. Best regards